# DB2 order by clause gives different results on different OS

Tags: sql, sorting, db2, db2-luw

I am trying out a simple SQL to sort varchar column using order by clause in DB2.

Query is something like :

```
select * from ThirdParty where ThirdPartyKy > 10001 order by ThirdPartyName
```

The sample data I've for ThirdPartyName columns is (Not necessarily in the same order) :

ThirdPartyName :

```
'AA'
'bb'
'CC'
'BB'
'aa'
'cc'
```

I am executing this query using SQuirrel against Local windows install of DB2 10.5 FP8 and against server install on AIX (same version).
I'm getting different output of above SQL on both these.

Output on DB2 - Windows

```
'aa'
'AA'
'bb'
'BB'
'cc'
'CC'
```

Output on DB2 - AIX

```
'AA'
'BB'
'CC'
'aa'
'bb'
'cc'
```

Now, I know that using 'upper(thirdpartyname)' will give me results what I want i.e. String starting with Special Characters first, numeric and then case insensitive string sorting.
I am unable to understand why would the behavior be different? Has anyone observed the same behavior for DB2?
I've also started wondering what else I've to be careful about.

Comment: Different language/locale settings.

Comment: As you are using Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, compare the "Database collating Sequence" for each database, along with the 'Database territory' and 'Database code set'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort order for strings in Db2, and in most of the other database systems, depends on the settings for the database system and database (and sometimes table and column).

My guess is that your settings differ. Do the databases have the same codepage? Do they have the same language? The same collating sequence?

Here is the link to string comparison rules. They determine the sort order:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html

Try the following to get databse details:

```
get db cfg
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The code set is UTF-8, code page is 1208 for Local Windows DB. Trying to figure out the same for Server AIX version. Territory is US.

Comment: OK. After getting right server access, I could compare the two database configurations. Not much difference. Typically we use the server/AIX db after converting it to windows format. In this case, the code page is 1208 for Both, Code set is UTF-8 for both and region is also same. I will do more research on sorting based on the article. Thanks again.

Comment: In the comment that you posted earlier, the collating sequence was different. That causes the different sort order.

Comment: Yes sure. I get it. I somehow ignored it earlier but then it struck me. Thanks a lot for on spot answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers. I found the difference between two databases.

Windows copy has following collating sequence : 
Database collating sequence                             = SYSTEM_1252

While AIX copy has following : 
Database collating sequence                             = IDENTITY

Related articles : 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006812.html ,  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0006813.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of collation installed on your differents system. A solution is to take same colation on install or rectif your query like it :

```
order by upper(ThirdPartyName)
```

Comment: Yes, I finally ended up changing the SQL this way. But I'm wondering if such differences in collating system in databases across OS is usual. In other words, should this be handled in SQL Or Database configurations. I would anyways make the application safe by using upper function ... just a thought ...